# Python function behaves unexpectedly

Tags: python, function, pandas

I am doing a very simple transformation on a pandas dataframe by using a function, but I didn't expect the function will change the input dataframe (but it did). I was wondering why...

Here's my code:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [3,4,5]})

def transform(df, increment):
    new_df = df
    new_df.a = new_df.a + increment
    return new_df

new_x = transform(x, 1)

new_x # output shows new_x.a is [2,3,4], which is expected.
x # output shows x.a is also [2,3,4]. I thought it should be [1,2,3]
```

Why is this the case? I think, in the function, all the operations are executed on the `new_df`, so the input `x` should stay exactly the same before and after I ran this `transform` function, isn't it?

Comment: `new_df = df` does *not* copies the dataframe. You simply make another reference to the *same* object.

Comment: Yes, `new_df` and `df` are two names for the same object.

Comment: `new_df = df.copy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because it does not create a copy, but another "reference" of the `x` 
object

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [3,4,5]})


def transform(df, increment):
    new_df = df.copy() # <--- piece to change
    new_df.a = new_df.a + increment
    return new_df

new_x = transform(x, 1)

new_x # output shows new_x.a is [2,3,4], which is expected.
x # output shows x.a is now [1,2,3].
```

When you add [`.copy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) this will give you the expected behavior